# Deleted swap that I created

Tags: linux, fedora, swap

I am running Fedora 29

I was trying some things so I created a swap partition at /var/tmp/swap_file

then I turned on the swap file. This caused me boot errors because it filled up my root directory.

I deleted the swap file w/o removing it from fstab and now the system will not boot; it stops at systemctl error missing dependency.

How can I get the system to disable that swap file dependency so that I can boot back into my system.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Booting_to_Emergency_Mode.html

This article lets you know how to enter the emergency mode, which will essentially mount the system in a read only format. You will need to remount the system in rw to be able to edit your `fstab` and remove the invalid swap line

You can remount the filesystem by running:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

You should then be able to `vim /etc/fstab`